# Log Azure AD e-mail into ASP.NET Identity tables

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I'm making a report system which allows users to login using Azure credentials which then they'll subscribe/unsubscribe to reports.

It's currently using ASP.NET Identity which works perfectly but requires more IT support with people forgetting their credentials etc.

How would I save the Azure credentials into ASP.NET Identity? Like it does with other external providers like Facebook and so on or would you avoid using ASP.NET Identity all together and save the e-mail address to a table and reference that table instead of the ASP.NET Identity version?

Startup.cs

```
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

            // Per the code below, this application signs in users in any Work and School
            // accounts and any Microsoft Personal Accounts.
            // If you want to direct Azure AD to restrict the users that can sign-in, change 
            // the tenant value of the appsettings.json file in the following way:
            // - only Work and School accounts => 'organizations'
            // - only Microsoft Personal accounts => 'consumers'
            // - Work and School and Personal accounts => 'common'

            // If you want to restrict the users that can sign-in to only one tenant
            // set the tenant value in the appsettings.json file to the tenant ID of this
            // organization, and set ValidateIssuer below to true.

            // If you want to restrict the users that can sign-in to several organizations
            // Set the tenant value in the appsettings.json file to 'organizations', set
            // ValidateIssuer, above to 'true', and add the issuers you want to accept to the
            // options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers collection
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

            // Custom
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            //options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            };
        });
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
For now, I'm just using TokenValidated event then create user using UserManager with CreateAsync.

Answer (score 1):

If using asp.net core identity with Azure AD as external identity provider . After login using AAD , asp.net identity will help creating a local user , user can input his AAD email so that in database you can know which local user is associated with specific Azure AD user . You can then implement custom logic like authorization in local database .But the local user won't affect the AAD user , change local account's credential won't affect AAD user's credential in cloud . The next time , you still need to login using AAD as identity provider rather than local user account .

You don't need and should not save Azure credentials into local database . If you want to reset a specific user's credential ,  You can use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/asp.net) to [update a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) . Your admin(IT) user should have the correct permission(`User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.ReadWrite.All` delegated permissions) to change other user's information in the tenant .

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) is Microsoft Graph Auth document and [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample) is code sample for ASP.NET Core .

Comment: That's what I wanted to happen, you logged into AAD and ASP.NET Identity would create a local account for you. I don't really care about user been able to login using that local account, it's just used to get the e-mail address for when the user subscribes to reports. My 2 thoughts were; Either log the e-mail address to a table and use that as new reference once user has logged in using AAD or integrate AAD with ASP.NET Identity so if I ever added any other external providers (don't have any plans to do so) that I could keep it all standard without any database changes. Thanks.

Comment: Yes , ASP.NET identity have a table(`AspNetUserLogins` table) shows which local user associate with which cloud user of which identity provider . You can check that , asp.net identity will let user enter his  email address after login from external providers  and if confirming that no exist local user associate with that account .

Comment: Don't forget to use `"CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"` in AAD config as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875422/hybrid-authentication-in-net-core-with-open-id-connect-and-local-database/54880889#54880889)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think saving the Azure credentials into ASP.NET Identity is a helpful way to achieve your goal.

If you want to use Azure credentials to log in, what you need is integrating Azure AD into your ASP.NET Core Web App to enabling users to sign-in with a work and school account.

Detailed steps/samples for quick start here: [Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) and [Azure Active Directory with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-3.0).