# Hybrid User Identity in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I followed the following steps to create a hybrid login solution
[Hybrid authentication in .net core with Open Id Connect and local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875422/hybrid-authentication-in-net-core-with-open-id-connect-and-local-database)

When running the app and then clicking on Azure Active Directory login button, I receive the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden]'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateIssuer(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

appsettings.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-Hybrid2-365BF50C-5C76-40EB-820E-59075FF471D7;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
        "TenantId": "common",
        "ClientId": "9407cd54-e564-4e15-b9e0-aabd750037c0",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is multi-tenant application since you are requesting to `/common` endpoint  , you need to disable the issuer validation :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

});
```

The `/common` endpoint is not a tenant and is not an issuer, it’s just a multiplexer. When using `/common`,  the logic in your application to validate tokens should decide which issuer values are valid and which are not based on the tenant ID portion of the issuer value. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values) for more details .

Comment: How do I implement role based management on this Hybrid solution ? I'm struggling to find any related tutorials that handles this  ? So I basically want to create, assign roles to users ?

Comment: You need to manage user/roles in asp.net core identity , then in OIDC middleware , in `OnTokenValidated ` you can query the database and add to user claims , so that you can use user.isinrole or use authorize attribute with specific roles . See code sample here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572399/5751404